# Create pd.DataFrame from dictionary with multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've the following dictionary:

```
dictA = {'A': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]],
         'B': [[4, 4, 4], [4, 4, 4],],
         'C': [[4, 6, 0]]
        }
```

I want to convert it to a `pd.DataFrame()`, expecting this:

```
id       ColA        ColB        ColC
0         1           4           4
1         2           4           6
2         3           4           0
3         1           4           
4         2           4
5         3           4
6         1
7         2
8         3
```

How can I do that?
I'm trying

```
pd.DataFrame(dictAll.items(), columns=['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC'])
```

But it obviously doesn't work!

Comment: you can use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictA)` but the arrays on the dict need to be the same length all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dictA = {'A': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]],
         'B': [[4, 4, 4], [4, 4, 4],],
         'C': [[4, 6, 0]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict([(f'Col{k}', pd.Series([a for b in v for a in b])) for k,v in dictA.items()])).replace(np.nan, '')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ColA ColB ColC
0     1    4    4
1     2    4    6
2     3    4    0
3     1    4     
4     2    4     
5     3    4     
6     1          
7     2          
8     3
```

---

Now, let's have a look at the problem one step at a time.

1. The first thing we might try is simply:

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame(dictA)
   print(df)
   ```

   Which, of course, return this error:

   ```
    ValueError: arrays must all be same length
   ```
2. So now we need a way to be able to create dataframes from a `dict` with arrays of different lengths. For that, we can:

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k, pd.Series(v)) for k, v in dictA.items()]))
   print(df)
   ```

   Output:

   ```
              A          B          C
   0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 4, 4]  [4, 6, 0]
   1  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 4, 4]        NaN
   2  [1, 2, 3]        NaN        NaN
   ```
3. We want the dataframe to be vertical, so for each iteration, flatten out the lists with a list comprehension:

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k, pd.Series([a for b in v for a in b])) for k, v in dictA.items()]))
   print(df)
   ```

   Output:

   ```
      A    B    C
   0  1  4.0  4.0
   1  2  4.0  6.0
   2  3  4.0  0.0
   3  1  4.0  NaN
   4  2  4.0  NaN
   5  3  4.0  NaN
   6  1  NaN  NaN
   7  2  NaN  NaN
   8  3  NaN  NaN
   ```
4. Now we want to replace all the `NaN`s with blanks. For that, we need to `import numpy as np`, and do:

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k, pd.Series([a for b in v for a in b])) for k, v in dictA.items()])).replace(np.nan, '')
   print(df)
   ```

   Output:

   ```
      A  B  C
   0  1  4  4
   1  2  4  6
   2  3  4  0
   3  1  4   
   4  2  4   
   5  3  4   
   6  1      
   7  2      
   8  3
   ```
5. Finally use formatted string to convert the letters into `"Col"` letters:

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame(dict([(f'Col{k}', pd.Series([a for b in v for a in b])) for k,v in dictA.items()])).replace(np.nan, '')
   print(df)
   ```

   Output:

   ```
      ColA ColB ColC
   0     1    4    4
   1     2    4    6
   2     3    4    0
   3     1    4     
   4     2    4     
   5     3    4     
   6     1          
   7     2          
   8     3
   ```